# React Native: Center MapBox in a given area, not just in center coordinate

Tags: reactjs, react-native, mapbox, mapbox-gl, mapbox-gl-js

Here I am trying to achieve centering a `MapBox` map in a given area:

- The area can be defined ideally by a (sub) set of annotations
- Alternatively it can just be an a rectangle for simplicity

From what I know from its documentation, `MapBox` only allows centering in a single `centerCoordinate` and setting `zoomLevel`. By setting `zoomLevel` there seems to be no guarantee that the rectangle will be contained inside the `MapBox`.

How to achieve a whole area being displayed at once and the map being centered around it?

```
<Mapbox
  accessToken={'ACCESS_TOKEN'}
  centerCoordinate={this.state.currentView.coordinates}
  zoomLevel={this.state.currentView.zoomLevel}
/>
```

Answer (score 2):

The [`Map#fitBounds`](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#Map#fitBounds) method seems to do exactly what you're looking for. I'm not sure if / how to use it with the react wrapper, however.

Comment: I would look for existing implementations. As you said it exists, should be possible to implement wrapper in React.